# SSMS vs SSIS Performance challenges

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012

Queries run faster in SSMS than when executed thru SSIS?? 
Any reason, same exact query when executed in SSMS takes 30 seconds to complete and when run through SSIS takes 2 minutes??

One of my senior colleague says we're not optimized or configured to run SSIS.
Is that true??
If so what are the configurations do we need to do for SSIS.
Note: Recently started using SSIS, there are no datawarehousing environment or setup. 
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: SSIS is an ETL tool - you don't need to have a warehouse to use SSIS.  What is the configuration of your SSIS environment?  How are you running the packages?

Comment: I don't know anything about SSIS configuration environment. I'm running SSIS packages locally didn't deploy them yet.

Comment: Is there standard configuration info for SSIS. If so i don't think we have followed that. Hopefully thats what my senior colleague is talking about but i'm not sure what it is.

Comment: What driver are you using to run the SQL code?

Answer (score 0):

Check for [parameter sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parameter%20sniffing).  This has been a culprit in a couple of cases for me.  Also check to make sure you are using the correct OLEDB driver for your SQL Server.

Comment: No parameter passing actually there is no where clause. I double checked execution plan as well and everything looked good. Using correct OLEDB driver.

Comment: Here's one way you can find the difference: Run a trace on the server side and capture the queries from SSMS vs SSIS.  compare execution plans.